# Need help extracting information out of a JSON file in python

Tags: python, json, extract

I need to extract the keys out of this JSON file on python, how would I go about this?

```
{
    "expand": "schema,names",
    "issues": [
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "10012",
            "key": "SM-2",
            "self": "https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10012"
        },
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "10013",
            "key": "SM-3",
            "self": "https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10013"
        },
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "10014",
            "key": "SM-4",
            "self": "https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10014"
        },
    ],
    "maxResults": 50,
    "startAt": 0,
    "total": 3
}
```

For example I want to create a list like ["SM-2", "SM-3", "SM-4"]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Have you looked into the `json` module? Parsed the JSON? Do you know how to deal with lists and dictionaries?

Comment: Use the `json` module in the standard library... There are many examples of this online

Comment: How would you do it if you just had that data structure?

Comment: I have never used json before so needed some help... couldnt find any examples like this online but if there is my bad!

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is in wrong format
for this JSON

```
[
    {
    "expand": "schema,names",
    "issues": [
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "10012",
            "key": "SM-2",
            "self": "https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10012"
        },
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "10013",
            "key": "SM-3",
            "self": "https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10013"
        },
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "10014",
            "key": "SM-4",
            "self": "https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10014"
        }
    ],
    "maxResults": 50,
    "startAt": 0,
    "total": 3
    }
]
```

Try this code

```
import json
j = json.load(open('Json.json', 'r'))

for d in j[0]['issues']:
    print(d['key'])
```

Answer (score 0):

the json you post is not good, hope it was an example..
JSON dos no accept "," extra commas

```
{
    "expand": "schema,names",
    "issues": [
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "10012",
            "key": "SM-2",
            "self": "https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10012"
        },
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "10013",
            "key": "SM-3",
            "self": "https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10013"
        },
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "10014",
            "key": "SM-4",
            "self": "https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10014"
        },    <<<<<<  THIS COMMA is not acceptable in a valid json !!!!
    ],
    "maxResults": 50,
    "startAt": 0,
    "total": 3
}
```

using ipython

```py
In [8]: import json
       ...:
       ...: r = '{\
       ...:     "expand": "schema,names",\
       ...:     "issues": [\
       ...:         {\
       ...:             "expand": 
 "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",\
       ...:             "id": "10012",\
       ...:             "key": "SM-2",\
       ...:             "self": "https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10012"\
       ...:         },\
       ...:         {\
       ...:             "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",\
       ...:             "id": "10013",\
       ...:             "key": "SM-3",\
       ...:             "self": "https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10013"\
       ...:         },\
       ...:         {\
       ...:             "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",\
       ...:             "id": "10014",\
       ...:             "key": "SM-4",\
       ...:             "self": "https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10014"\
       ...:         }\
       ...:     ],\
       ...:     "maxResults": 50,\
       ...:     "startAt": 0,\
       ...:     "total": 3\
       ...: }'
       ...:

    In [9]: j = json.loads(r)

    In [10]: j['issues']
    Out[10]:
    [{'expand': 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields',
      'id': '10012',
      'key': 'SM-2',
      'self': 'https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10012'},
     {'expand': 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields',
      'id': '10013',
      'key': 'SM-3',
      'self': 'https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10013'},
     {'expand': 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields',
      'id': '10014',
      'key': 'SM-4',
      'self': 'https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10014'}]

    In [11]: l = j['issues']

    In [12]: for issue in l:
        ...:     print(l)
        ...:
    [{'expand': 
     'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields', 'id': '10012', 'key': 'SM-2', 'self': 
    'https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10012'}, {'expand': 
    'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields', 'id': 
    '10013', 'key': 'SM-3', 'self': 
    'https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10013'}, {'expand': 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields', 'id': '10014', 'key': 'SM-4', 'self': 'https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10014'}]
    [{'expand': 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields', 'id': '10012', 'key': 'SM-2', 'self': 'https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10012'}, {'expand': 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields', 'id': '10013', 'key': 'SM-3', 'self': 'https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10013'}, {'expand': 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields', 'id': '10014', 'key': 'SM-4', 'self': 'https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10014'}]
    [{'expand': 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields', 'id': '10012', 'key': 'SM-2', 'self': 'https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10012'}, {'expand': 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields', 'id': '10013', 'key': 'SM-3', 'self': 'https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10013'}, {'expand': 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields', 'id': '10014', 'key': 'SM-4', 'self': 'https://isml.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10014'}]
```